# Laravel - Merge each two rows in a table with additional two column for each row value

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table with records as follows:

| id | entry_id | type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | in | 500 |
| 2 | 1 | out | 600 |
| 3 | 2 | in | 100 |
| 4 | 2 | out | 20000 |

I want have a query to merge rows based on the entry_id to get a table as this:

| id | entry_id | in_amount | out_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 | 600 |
| 3 | 2 | 100 | 20000 |

I want to perform this using PHP Laravel.

I tried using group concat but I didn't get the desired outcome.

Here is my code attempt:

```
DB::table('entry_entities')
        ->selectRaw("
            entry_entities.entry_id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(entry_entities.entity_type, '-', entry_entities.account_id) as account_ids
        ")
        ->groupBy('entry_entities.entry_id')
        ->get()
        ->map(function($row) {
            $accountIds = explode(',', $row->account_ids);
            foreach($accountIds as $account) {
                [$key, $value] = explode('-', $account);
                $row->{$key} = $value;
            }
            return $row;
        });
```

This is not a valid attempt because I need a query I can use as a subquery for another. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also show us your current code attempt?

Comment: How about something like this?  SELECT MIN(id) AS id, entry_id, SUM(IF(type = "in", amount, NULL)) AS in_amount, SUM(IF(type = "out", amount, NULL)) AS out_amount FROM my_table GROUP BY entry_id

Comment: The amount in the example is not the actual column, but I used it for clarification. The actual column is a foreign key.

Comment: Thank you @RobEyre. I was able to solve it using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
EntryEntity::selectRaw ('entry_id, ' . 
                        "round (sum(if(type = 'in', amount, 0)) / " . 
                        "count(if(type = 'in', entry_id, NULL)), 0) as 'in_amount', " . 
                        "round (sum(if(type = 'out', amount, 0)) / " . 
                        "count(if(type = 'out', id, NULL)), 0) as 'out_amount'")
           ->groupBy ('entry_id')
           ->get();
```